# Invert array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a `string[][]`.
Each entry in the list represents a column in a document, each member of the array represents a line in this column.
Example:

```
0.0 | 1.0 | 2.0  
0.1 | 1.1 | 2.1  
0.2 | 1.2 | 2.2
```

Now I to write this to a file. However if I do that I first need to convert them to string[] where each element is one line, joined by let's say commas (.csv file).

Any suggestions how to do that?

I tried wrapping my head around it with several loops taking the n-th element of each column and stuff it in a buffer and then join these buffers together. I am sure I will get it to work that way, however I don't think that it is in any way efficient or good style.

Comment: @SatelliteSD actually it is part of a replacement for a god-awful VBA-AddIn for Excel used by my employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting with this:

```
string[][] original = new[] {
    new[] { "0.0", "0.1", "0.2" },
    new[] { "1.0", "1.1", "1.2" },
    new[] { "2.0", "2.1", "2.2" }
};
```

Then you can do this to work with each row in turn:

```
for (int column = 0; column < original.Length; column++)
{
    string row = string.Join(",", original.Select(o => o[column]));
    Console.WriteLine(row);    
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
0.0,1.0,2.0
0.1,1.1,2.1
0.2,1.2,2.2
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about something like this but somehow it was way more complicated

Answer (score 3):

Ok simple: assume that the entire array is rectangular (i.e. same number of items in all rows and same number of items in all columns). What you have to do now, is given an item at (x,y), change its position to (y,x).

So:

```
var array2 = new string[array1.GetLength(0), array1.GetLength(1)];
for(int i=0;i<array2.GetLength(0);i++){
    for(int j=0;j<array2.GetLength(1);j++)
        array2[i,j] = array1[j][i]; //this is the magic line
}
```

Comment: I wonder why I get a negative vote immediately after I post this with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, that's what some people do :\

Comment: +1 for better comprehensibility and flexibility. However the other answer is closer to my desired output.